# Typographic apostrophe in title leads to hyphen in URL slug

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, title, unicode, slug

The question title `Foo's bar` leads to the slug `/foos-bar`.
The question title `Foo’s bar` leads to the slug `/foo-s-bar`.

So for the slug generation, the "typewriter apostrophe" `'` (U+0027) gets stripped while the "typographic apostrophe" `’` (U+2019) gets replaced with `-`.

I think both characters should be handled in the same way, and I think stripping the character is the better choice: the `’` character can be used as apostrophe and as quotation mark, and in both cases a delimiter like `-` is not needed.

Comment: Unicode is vast and varied. I certainly wouldn't classify this as a bug, at most you could make it a feature request to extend the handling of punctuation. Perhaps the Unicode P* classes (punctuation, U+2019 is class Pf) could be so treated, but that'd take more research.

Comment: In any case, URL slugs are aimed at search engines more than anything else.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Made it a feature request.